# Generating very small sized thumbnails from featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I want to create very tiny thumbnails that I can use in my sidebar. I want them to be around 5kb in size and be created automatically from the featured images.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the size of the image, but I assume small images that have a dimension about 50px should have the size around 5 or 10kb. You can add your own custom size to your theme:

```
add_image_size( 'tiny-thumbnails', 50, 50, true );
```

Setting the fourth parameter to `true` will force the WordPress to crop the thumbnails, so they will be exactly 50px in width and 50px in height.

Now, calling this function will get you your tiny thumbnails:

```
the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id ,'tiny-thumbnails' );
```

Don't forget to regenerate the thumbnails after adding this code to your theme's `functions.php` file.

You can also tweak with the JPG quality, to reduce the size of your thumbnails (which also reduces the quality!). The `jpeg_quality` filter allows you to do this.

```
// Set your quality to any value you wish. Values below 70 are not recommended
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){ return 85; });
```